# Standard deviation of error (SDE) application

Tags: standard-deviation, terminology, standard-error, measurement-error

There are *standard deviation*, *standard error* (SE), *standard error of mean* (SEM), then there is *standard deviation of error* (SDE) intended as a measure of error variability used in device measurement accuracy evaluation as example domain. What is the SDE formula, meaning and difference to SE and SEM. Is SDE the same as a root mean squared error (RMSE)?